# Creating an abstract syntax tree for code that has multiple lines

Tags: compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, yacc

What is the general practice when it comes to creating AST from multiple lines of code? For example if I was writing a translator to translate code from one language to another, and I encountered a set of statements like this:

```
x = 2
f = k->o
a = 1+2*3
```

I can successfully create ASTs for each of the individual lines of code here. Now, while having to generate the translated code, would I be better served having one AST instead of n ASTs if the code is n lines long? And if so, how is that single AST formed?

Comment: If you like, you can combine individual statement ASTs into block or compound statement ASTs, which in turn can be combined with other sub-trees into function/method trees, all the way up to complete program trees (one AST for a whole program).

Comment: The idea is to have one AST on top of the hierarchy. When you wan't to call some method, you call it on that top AST, and recursion will do the job for rest of it.

Comment: Use the One Big Tree approach.  Implement this with a tree node called "sequential_statement" with a left child consisting of a statement, and the right child being another "sequential_statement" node or a dummy "end of list" node.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you probably shouldn't be thinking in terms of "lines of code" any more. The input to the parser is a stream of tokens. You *do* have a lexer, don't you? :-)

It's perfectly fine (and normal) for the AST to span many statements. Indeed, it would typically span the entire unit of compilation, such as a single function or even an entire module (read: source file).

For example, consider this program:

```
fun f(x, y) {
    z = x + y;
    if (z > 3) {
        return z; 
    } else {
        return g(x);
    }
}

fun g(x) {
    return x * 2;
}
```

The compiler might build an AST that looks something like this (please ignore the specifics and focus on the general structure):

```
ModNode
  FunNode[Name = "f"]
    CompoundStmtNode
      AssignStmtNode
        VarNode[Name = "z"]
        BinExprNode[Oper = "+"]
          VarNode[Name = "x"]
          VarNode[Name = "y"]
      IfStmtNode
        BinExprNode[Oper = ">"]
          VarNode[Name = "z"]
          ConstNode[Value = 3]
        CompoundStmtNode
          ReturnNode
            VarNode[Name = "z"]
        CompoundStmtNode
          ReturnNode
            CallNode[Name = "g"]
              VarNode[Name = "x"]
  FunNode[Name = "g"]
    CompoundStmtNode
      ReturnNode
        BinExprNode[Oper = "*"]
          VarNode[Name = "x"]
          ConstNode[Value = 2]
```

The benefit of building an AST for the entire source file is that it's easy to perform multiple logical passes over the code (for example, in order to resolve forward references). The downside, of course, is that AST's can get pretty large.

Answer (score -1):

I would advice you have one Ast made of smaller Asts. And use recursion to traverse through them. For the design of the tree you can choose either side. But I would use the right side for each line and the left to point to the next line of code. To draw it out. I'm gonna assume you know how to parse through an assignNode and exprNode and just show the bigger picture

x = 2

f = k->o

a = 1+2*3

So for this you have.

```
                                   [AssignNode]
                          left                      right
                      [AssignNode]                  [x=2]
              left                   right  
           [AssignNode]             [f=k->o]
     left                right
    [Null]            a = [ExprNode]

                           [1]  +   [2*3]
```

Traversal would be start with going right and go till we hit null. Once we hit null return back to the node and go left.

Since this is one Ast made up of smaller ones. Each time we hit a new Node/Ast we will do the same traversal and go right then left.

Giving us 
go right get x=2
then hit null return and go left.
Get to AssignNode
go right get f=k->o
then hit null return and go left.
Get AssignNode
go right get a=ExprNode
Go right and parse the ExprNode return 
and finish assignNode return 
and go left. 
Left is null were done.